# Why does summary overestimate the R-squared with a "no-intercept" model formula

Tags: r, summary, intercept, lm

I wanted to make a simple linear model (`lm()`) without intercept coefficient so I put `-1` in my model formula as in the following example. The problem is that the R-squared return by `summary(myModel)` seems to be overestimated. `lm()`, `summary()` and `-1` are among the very classic function/functionality in R. Hence I am a bit surprised and I wonder if this is a bug or if there is any reason for this behaviour.

Here is an example:

```
x <- rnorm(1000, 3, 1)
mydf <- data.frame(x=x, y=1+x+rnorm(1000, 0, 1))
plot(y ~ x, mydf, xlim=c(-2, 10), ylim=c(-2, 10))

mylm1 <- lm(y ~ x, mydf)
mylm2 <- lm(y ~ x - 1, mydf)

abline(mylm1, col="blue") ; abline(mylm2, col="red")
abline(h=0, lty=2) ; abline(v=0, lty=2)

r2.1 <- 1 - var(residuals(mylm1))/var(mydf$y)
r2.2 <- 1 - var(residuals(mylm2))/var(mydf$y)
r2 <- c(paste0("Intercept - r2: ", format(summary(mylm1)$r.squared, digits=4)),
        paste0("Intercept - manual r2: ", format(r2.1, digits=4)),
        paste0("No intercept - r2: ", format(summary(mylm2)$r.squared, digits=4)),
        paste0("No intercept - manual r2: ", format(r2.2, digits=4)))
legend('bottomright', legend=r2, col=c(4,4,2,2), lty=1, cex=0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: This is really a statistical understanding question; I flagged it to be migrated to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)--ie, stats.SE (*please don't cross-post, however*). In the interim, you will want to read this CV post: [removal of statistically significant intercept term boosts r2 in linear model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/), particularly the excellent answer by @cardinal.

Comment: What R is doing in this case is so non-obvious to many that it warrants its own FAQ [entry](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-does-summary_0028_0029-report-strange-results-for-the-R_005e2-estimate-when-I-fit-a-linear-model-with-no-intercept_003f). You might want to check that out and confirm you are using the same approach to compare.

Comment: @Gavin I am glad I'm not the only one who finds this R behaviour strange, thanks for the link! I myself found out the hard way, but at least I understand *what* happens (unfortunatelly not *why* :-)), see my answer

Comment: Note that not only R^2 is strange but also F-statistic and its p-value.

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing your experience and your knowledge. In particular to gung,  Gavin Simpson, Dirk Eddelbuettel and Tomas for your comments and answer that saved my time. I am so used to find answers to my R programming questions on this website that I forgot to check out Cross validated and R FAQ websites. Anyway I am definitely clear about this issue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. Here is what I do in `fastLm.R` in [RcppArmadillo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) when computing the summary:

```
## cf src/library/stats/R/lm.R and case with no weights and an intercept 
f <- object$fitted.values    
r <- object$residuals         
mss <- if (object$intercept) sum((f - mean(f))^2) else sum(f^2)     
rss <- sum(r^2)   

r.squared <- mss/(mss + rss) 
df.int <- if (object$intercept) 1L else 0L    

n <- length(f)     
rdf <- object$df     
adj.r.squared <- 1 - (1 - r.squared) * ((n - df.int)/rdf)
```

There are two places where you need to keep track of whether there is an intercept or not.

Answer (score 11):

Oh yeah, I fell into this trap too! Very good question!! It is because

[image]

and

[image]

- in case of model *with* intercept (your `mylm1`), the y̅ is mean(y<sub>i</sub>) - this is what you expect, this is the SS<sub>tot</sub> you basicly want for proper R<sup>2</sup>
- whereas in case of model *without* intercept, the y̅ is taken as 0 - so the  SS<sub>tot</sub> will be very high, so the R<sup>2</sup> will be very close to 1! SS<sub>res</sub> will differ according to the worse fit (will be little higher *without* intercept), but not much.

Code:

```
attach(mylm1) # in general be careful with attach, here only for code clarity

y_fit <- mylm1$fitted.values
SSE <- sum((y_fit - y)^2)
SST <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)
1-SSE/SST  # R^2 with intercept

y_fit2 <- mylm2$fitted.values
SSE2 <- sum((y_fit2 - y)^2) # SSE2 only slightly higher than SSE..
SST2 <- sum((y - 0)^2)  # !!! the key difference is here !!!
1-SSE2/SST2 # R^2 without intercept
```

Note: It is not clear to me why in the model without intercept the y̅ is 0 and not mean(y<sub>i</sub>), but that's how it is. I myself found out hard way by investigating and hacking with the above code..

Comment: Why the model without intercept compares with zero instead of the mean is explained by the last sentence of the [FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-does-summary_0028_0029-report-strange-results-for-the-R_005e2-estimate-when-I-fit-a-linear-model-with-no-intercept_003f): "... if you know a priori that E[Y]=0 when x=0 then the ‘null’ model that you should compare to the fitted line, the model where x doesn’t explain any of the variance, is the model where E[Y]=0 everywhere."

Comment: This is the Gavin's link, good to know the official answer. The argumentation is controversial though: they shouldn't implicitly *assume* E[Y]=0. There are legitimate cases when E[Y]<>0 and you don't want the intercept (e.g. to receive "reasonable" coefficients for all categorical covariates, see [example 1 in this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32518/5509)).

Comment: I suppose, so, yes.  But that's a situation where the coding doesn't match the intent.  That is, even though there's no intercept term in the coding of the formula, you want to compare against a model with an intercept term.